# Use promise succes for event on click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have problem with return value of an async `$.post` value on a click method.

I have several sentences on my webpage, what I want to translate with ajax calls. I do not want to make it async, so please, do not advise it. When a page loads, there will be 4-5 or more sentences, and I want it to translate them "on the fly".

Finally, I found a solution, how to use the return value from an async call, but I guess, because it async, this is why not my `e.preventDefault()` triggered.

From this point, I do not know, how could I solve it.

```
$.translate = function (string) {
    return $.post(getBaseUrl() + 'ajax.php', {action: 'translate', text: string}, function () {});
};

$('td.operations a.remove').click(function (e) {
    var promise = $.translate('Do you really want to hurt me?');
    promise.success(function(data){
        console.log(e);
        if (!confirm(data)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

The `e` is a click event, that's ok. So, can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reverse your logic and prevent default behaviour all time for anchor click and call native click DOM method when needed, e.g:

```
$('td.operations a.remove').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this); // keep ref using closure (or you could bind it to promise callback)
    var promise = $.translate('Do you really want to hurt me?');
    promise.done(function(data){
        if (confirm(data)) {
            $self.off('click').get(0).click(); // call native click method
        }
    });
});
```

FYI, `success` method of deferred object is deprecated, use `done` instead.

Comment: Works great. Thank you.